# SignalR & SimpleInjector silently failing between hub and frontend

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I'm trying to set up a signalr hub on my project, using simpleinjector for dependency injection.

I have some configuration in Startup.cs

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))]

namespace CallCentre.Client
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var container = new Container();
            container.Register<TwilioHub>();
            container.Verify();
            var config = new HubConfiguration()
            {
                Resolver = new SignalRSimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container)
            };
            app.MapSignalR(config);
        }
    }
}
```

DI Resolver

```
public class SignalRSimpleInjectorDependencyResolver : DefaultDependencyResolver
    {
        private readonly Container _container;
        public SignalRSimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(Container container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }
        public override object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            return ((IServiceProvider)_container).GetService(serviceType)
                   ?? base.GetService(serviceType);
        }

        public override IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            return _container.GetAllInstances(serviceType)
                .Concat(base.GetServices(serviceType));
        }
    }
```

My hub

```
public class TwilioHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(int callCount, int queueId)
    {
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TwilioHub>();
        context.Clients.All.updateQueueCount(callCount, queueId);
    }
}
```

A class elsewhere in the solution where the hub is called

```
public class QueueStateHandler : IQueueStateHandler
{
    private readonly TwilioHub _twilioHub;


    public QueueStateHandler(TwilioHub twilioHub)
    {
        _twilioHub = twilioHub;
    }

    public void IncrementQueueById(int id)
    {
        _twilioHub.Send(5,1);
    }
}
```

And my frontend code

```
$(function () {
        var hub = $.connection.twilioHub;
        hub.logging = true;
        var queue = $('#QueueCount');
        hub.client.updateQueueCount = function(queueCount, id) {
            alert(queueCount);
        };
        $.connection.hub.start();
    });
```

I can set everything up using straight web api, skipping the DI and everything works fine.  As soon as I bring in DI I start running into problems.  At the moment its silently falling over somewhere. I can step through the code and end up in the hub, but nothing happens in my frontend.

Any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm seeing the same behavior.